# Python: Filtering CSV with NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter, nan

I've got a csv that looks like this, named 'output_data.csv':

```
date         product       conditional      client       time       termination_date
18/04/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
19/04/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
20/04/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
21/04/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
22/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
23/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
24/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         NaN
18/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
19/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
20/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
21/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
22/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
23/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
24/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
```

And I'm trying to write a simple line in my code to filter out any rows that have termination_date < date.

So the output would look something like this:

```
date         product       conditional      client       time       termination_date
19/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
19/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
20/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
21/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
22/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
23/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
24/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 1       10         
18/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
19/05/2020   Test 1        TRUE             Test 2       10         19/05/2020
```

I've used the code below before successfully, but this time I'm getting a blank csv instead:

```
output_data = output_data.loc[output_data['termination_date'] > output_data['date']]
```

I believe it might be because of the NaN values, however I'm not sure.

Does anyone know what alterations I can make to this line of code to ignore those values and provide the output that I mentioned?

Many thanks in advance!

===EDIT===

Sorry guys, looks like the filter was fine, but before this piece of code I was turning all my termination_date into NaN with the following script:

```
    output['termination_date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_data['termination_date'], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

This was an attempt to make the termination_date into a timestamp I could use to filter, but errors='coerce' turns all values into NaN, because without it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2019-07-30 00:00:00+00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

This is because the original termination_date is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00" so I was trying to turn it into the same format as the rest of my script: "dd/mm/yyyy".

So I guess the question now is, how can I turn the original date into dd/mm/yyyy, without having to pass errors='coerce' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the case with the direction of your inequality. It should be:

```py
output_data = output_data.loc[output_data['termination_date'] < output_data['date']]
```

Moreover, if you would like to keep the Nan values, you can use:

```py
output_data = output_data.loc[(output_data['termination_date'] < output_data['date']) | (output_data['termination_date'].isna())]
```

#### Edit:

According to the edited part of your post, you are converting the column to the datetime type but you are using slashes instead of the hyphens that are presented in your data sample. You should modify that that in your function. You can also get rid of the *coerce* attribute or change it to *'ignore'*:

```py
output['termination_date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_data['termination_date'], errors='ignore', format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The first code still gives me a blank csv output, and the second one gives me all the ones without any filtering... Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: @MTavares It's hard to say. It isn't connected with the Nan values, I suppose. Could you provide us with more code you are executing?

Comment: I'm very sorry, while reviewing the rest of my code I realised the problem was coming from somewhere else. I've edited the original post with the rest of the problem, could you take a look please? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
df['termination_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['termination_date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df[df['termination_date'] > df['date']]
```

**Output**:

```
        date product  conditional  client  time termination_date
7 2020-05-18  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
```

And < gives this output:

```
df = df[df['termination_date'] < df['date']]
```

**Output:**

```
         date product  conditional  client  time termination_date
9  2020-05-20  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
10 2020-05-21  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
11 2020-05-22  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
12 2020-05-23  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
13 2020-05-24  Test 1         True  Test 2    10       2020-05-19
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is still giving me a blank csv output. Is it not related to some terminate_date values being blank?

Comment: What do you mean blank CSV output? How are you converting to CSV?

Comment: You are converting the CSV to DataFrame, removing the rows and adding back to the CSV right?

Comment: It wouldn't be the problem while saving the CSV, because the DataFrame is also empty. 
I'm actually very sorry, while reviewing the rest of my code I realised the problem was coming from somewhere else. I've edited the original post with the rest of the problem, could you take a look please? :)

Comment: You don't need to coerce, you can use errors='ignore'. It will just ignore the errors without converting them to NaT

Comment: I've tried that, but doing that means all termination_dates will remain in this format: 2020-05-19 00:00:00+00 and therefore I won't be able to do any filtering with it. I either get an error saying I can't use '<' with str and datetime, or an error saying 'Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects' :/